# Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (content) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, electron

So I will no longer use micro froentend to include this part of the application, so I did copy the source files into the main project. Installed packages, etc but when I went to run, I got this error on console:

```
Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (content) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You may be adding a ref to a function component
2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
3. You have multiple copies of React loaded
See https://reactjs.org/link/refs-must-have-owner for more information.
    at coerceRef (react-dom.development.js:13218:1)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:13448:1)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:13719:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14125:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17632:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19080:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021:1
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431:1)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020:1)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:6:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:8:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (ChannelName.tsx:4:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:59
```

it seems i didn't have any duplicate react version loaded:

```
> npm ls react
├─┬ @emotion/react@11.8.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @emotion/styled@11.8.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.4.4
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.71
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.70
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.4.4
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.4.4
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.4.4
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.4.4
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └─┬ rifm@0.12.1
│   └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/material@5.4.4
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react@11.2.7
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dnd@15.1.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-draggable@4.4.4
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-helmet-async@1.2.3
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-icons@4.3.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1
│ ├─┬ react-slidedown@2.4.7
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.3.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.2.1
│ │ ├─┬ mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-tabs@3.2.3
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-usestateref@1.0.8
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├── react@17.0.2
└─┬ styled-components@5.3.3
  └── react@17.0.2 deduped
```

I didn't have in the source code ref set to a string, only 3 uses like this:

return

the full code look like this:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from './ItemTypes.tsx';
import { DraggableBox } from './DraggableBox';
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import { ButtonBox, TextBox, CheckBox } from './Box';
import { ControlType } from './ControlType';
import { GiArrowCursor } from "react-icons/gi";

const styles = {
    width: 150,
    height: 400,
    border: '1px solid black',
    position: 'relative',
    background: 'RGB(240, 240, 240)'
};

const cursorPropStyle = {
    position:"absolute",
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
};

export const Container = () => {
    const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState({
       //a: { top: 20, left: 10, title: 'Button' },
    });
    
    const moveBox = useCallback((id, left, top) => {
        setBoxes(update(boxes, {
            [id]: {
                $merge: { left, top },
            },
        }));
    }, [boxes]);
    
    const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.BOX,
        drop(item, monitor) {
            const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
            let left = Math.round(item.left + delta.x);
            let top = Math.round(item.top + delta.y);
            moveBox(item.id, left, top);
            return undefined;
        },
    }), [moveBox]);

    return <div ref={drop} style={styles}>
                <div style={cursorPropStyle}>
                    <GiArrowCursor />
                </div>
                <DraggableBox top={30} left={10} key="a" id="a" title="button" controlType={ControlType.Button}>
                    <ButtonBox title="button"/>
                </DraggableBox>
                <DraggableBox top={60} left={10} key="b" id="b" title="" controlType={ControlType.TextBox}>
                    <TextBox/>
                </DraggableBox>
                <DraggableBox top={90} left={10} key="c" id="c" title="checkbox" controlType={ControlType.CheckBox}>
                    <CheckBox title="checkbox" />
                </DraggableBox>
            </div>;
};
```

How can I fix this?